# Classifying solutions of a certain Diophantine Equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

The following question arose from a problem I am working on.

> Let $N, k$ be positive integers. Consider the Diophantine equation in $a, b, c$:
> $$
> \frac{1}{a} + \frac{N - 1}{b} = \frac{N^k}{c}
> $$
> with the conditions $0 < b < N$ and $0 < a, c < N^k$.

I am interested in classifying all (integer) solutions of this equation. It is clear that given a solution $(a, b, c)$, we have solutions $(\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c)$ for positive integers $\lambda$ (as long as the two conditions are still met). Another thing I have noticed is that if $(a_1,b_1,c_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2,c_2)$ are solutions such that $a_1-a_2=b_1-b_2=c_1-c_2$, then $(a_1a_2,b_1b_2,c_1c_2)$ is also a solution (just subtract the two equations).

In addition, there is a class of solutions of the form
$$
a = c = \frac{N^k - 1}{N - 1}\, b
$$ for all $1 \leq b < N$, as it is clear that $(N^k - 1)/(N - 1)$ is an integer.

I would like to know whether this problem has been studied before; is there any research out there on this or similar Diophantine equations? Also, are there any known general techniques for attacking problems of this nature?

(Since I am not aware of the kind of techniques that may be useful, feel free to edit the tags accordingly)

Comment: I think it is a bad habit to make little changes to bring the question back to the front page.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich actually I needed an answer urgently- so, I wanted the question to be viewed by as many people as possible. I would have stopped doing it if I received a satisfactory answer. I am sorry if I did something that doesn't fit into the community standards.

Comment: @SayanDutta What is the background for the question that makes you need an answer urgently?

Comment: If you really need an answer urgently, hire a tutor.